# Not jumping to an iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I've got a page with an `iframe` in it.

The problem I have is: Everytime I get to the page, it jumps down (scrolls down automatically) to show the `ifrme`.

I want the users to read some text before going into the iframe.

So, how can I stop this from happening?

**Edit**

This is my iframe:

```
<iframe src="http:\\www.example.com" width=920 height=600 name = "example"></iframe>
```

Comment: remove a `#` from your page' url

Comment: Probably the page inside the iframe is using JavaScript to focus some element... don't think there's much you can do about it.